# MySQL Ведение лога запросов только одной базы данных

Tags: mysql

Включил логирование медленных запросов и запросов без индексов.

Файл `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Проблема в том, что логирование происходит всех баз данных.

Как сделать только одной?

Comment: Это глобальные настройки, так что должно быть никак. Либо все БД, либе не одного

Comment: в интернете нашел только один метод. Это хранения этих логов в БД и потом удалять не нужные логи других баз. http://serverfault.com/a/282319 попробуйте, если будет трудно, я переведу для вас

Comment: Спасибо вам. Я не силен в английском. Правильно ли я их понял. Они создали таблицу. Загрузили текстовый файл в эту таблицу. Предварительно распарсив текстовый файл. Ну, а дальше делай селекты к таблице.

Comment: да вы правильно поняли. они еще удалили не нужные базы.

Comment: Есть такая утилита mysqldumpslow. В ее хелпе написано mysqldumpslow --help.     -h HOSTNAME  hostname of db server for *-slow.log filename (can be wildcard), default is '*', i.e. match all  Что это означает? Мне кажется, что она позволяет указать имя БД. И из лога сделать новый текстовый файл с конкретными базами данных

Comment: если задача сделать новый тест файл из основного, тогда таких утилит думаю много. Но вы правы, попробуйте